# Backbone code in doc ready but not working

Tags: backbone.js

I'm going to lose it!!! how can this not be working

```
$(function() {
   var someView = new Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('.whatever'),
     ...

     render: function() {
       this.$el.append('AAARGH');
     }
   });

   // init view...
});
```

Cannot call method append of undefined, yet it is in ready block.

Comment: make sure  `$('.whatever') ` available before you init view

Comment: Is there a `.whatever`? The latest Backbone won't even get to `render` if there isn't (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/St5yd/). Do you have a demo of the problem?

Comment: @muistooshort there is a .whatever

Comment: Can you show us the problem happening in an example? Are you certain that you're looking at the right `append` call? A demo would clear things up and building the demo might even show you where your problem is.

Comment: @muistooshort guh, i was losing context of 'this' because i was using this.$el inside collection iterator, fiddle got me to the problem.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.$el
```

Instead of

```
  this.el
```

Comment: I do have that, sorry typo